# Modificar if else y trabajar con array, funcion medallasegunpuesto con javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio donde nos piden que desarrollemos la función medallaSegunPuesto, la cual retorne la medalla que le corresponde a los primeros puestos, según la siguiente lógica:

- Primer puesto: le corresponde "Oro"
- Segundo puesto: le corresponde "Plata"
- Tercer puesto: le corresponde "Bronce"
- Otros puestos: le corresponde "Seguí participando"

yo lo hice asi con if else:

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(a){
     if (a == 1) {
       return "Oro";
     } else if (a == 2){
       return "Plata";
     }else if (a == 3){
       return "Bronce";
     } else {
       return "Seguí participando"; 
     }
 }
```

Pero ahora necesito modificarlo pero esta vez usando como máximo un sólo if y utilizar array.

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(a){
    if(a>3)
        return "Seguí participando"; 
    return ["Oro","Plata","Bronce"][a-1];
}
```

O

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(a){
       return a>3?"Seguí participando":["Oro","Plata","Bronce"][a-1];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes proceder de esta forma:

- El argumento que vas a recibir cuando invoques a la función deberá tener una estructura de este tipo **`[valor1, valor2, ....., valorN]`** para que cumpla el punto de recibir un array
- Por dentro verificamos la longitud del vector, considerando que si solo los 3 pueden obtener medalla entonces evaluamos si la longitud es mayor a 3 entonces imprimimos el mensaje de sigue participando
- Para imprimir el resto de medallas que se pueden ganar lo hacemos antes del if ya mencionado

**Código**

```js
    function medallaSegunPuesto(posiciones) { 
      console.log(`Tu posición es ${posiciones[0]} y te toca oro`)
      console.log(`Tu posición es ${posiciones[1]} y te toca plata`)
      console.log(`Tu posición es ${posiciones[2]} y te toca bronce`)
    
      if(posiciones.length > 3) {
        console.log(`del cuarto lugar en adelante: Sigue participando`)
      }
      
    }
    
    medallaSegunPuesto([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con un diccionario:

ejemplo:

```js
var tipo_medalla = { 1 : "oro" ,2 : "plata", 3: "bronce"};

function medalla(posicion){
  // evaluamos si existe en el dicionario el numero
  // si no envia sigue participando
  /*
  if(tipo_medalla[posicion]){
    return tipo_medalla[posicion];
  }
  return "sigue participando";
  */
  
  // resumido seria
  return (  tipo_medalla[posicion] || "sigue participando" );
}

console.log(medalla(1));
console.log(medalla(2));
console.log(medalla(3));
console.log(medalla(4));
```